# Keyboard default binding to advance to next sheet in Windows Excel 2010?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010

Using the default bindings for Microsoft Excel 2010 on Windows 7, what keyboard binding exists (if any) that allows me to navigate to the next sheet in a spreadsheet?  What about the prior sheet?

I've tried various combinations of the Tab key with modifiers, but none seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next sheet: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>

Previous sheet: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Comment: @WilliamKF you're welcome, and thanks for welcoming me to the site. :P